# Getting error while calling variable at run time using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing, robotframework

If i do the execution in local it is working fine with the same command, But if i hit the same command in Jenkins Getting below error. Can someone please guide me on this.

As per my understanding this is an issue with IF ELSE coniditions. If i remove that conditoins and execute my script it is working fine. for IF ELSE condition we need to follow some order.If i keep my ELSE statement in very next to IF block we are getting different error. I update my code. M not sure still what order i need to follow

```
    cd C:\temp\workspace\UI-Testing\UI_Automation\
             IF "%Execution_File_Name%" == "Tests" (
                 pabot --testlevelsplit --processes 6 --ordering order_file.pabotsuitenames  
                 --variable URL:%URL% --variable project:%Project% --variable 
                 username:%UserName% --variable password:%Password% --removekeywords WUKS -d 
                 Results %Execution_File_Name%) ELSE (
                                                  robot --variable URL:%URL% --variable 
                                                  project:%Project% --variable 
                                                  username:%UserName% --variable 
                                                  password:%Password% --removekeywords WUKS 
                                                  -d Results Tests\%Execution_File_Name%)

exit 0
```

Getting below error in Jenkins as -

```
>    "Module execution started"
>[ ERROR ] Expected at least 1 argument, got 0.
>Try --help for usage information.
>The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Updated error:

```
    [ ERROR ] option --variable requires argument

Try --help for usage information.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
'-d' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: `Tests\%Execution_File_Name%` what was the evaluated value for this, or what was the evaluated command.

Comment: In my scenario i have two scenarios, one is fuu suite execution and second one module wise execution. In i want to do full suite execution then if condition will execute and if i want to do module wise execution it will come into else. Those modules are available inside of Test. So scenario will Tests\Dashboard

Comment: As per my understanding this is an issue with IF ELSE coniditions. If i remove that conditoins and execute my script it is working fine. for IF ELSE condition we need to follow some order.If i keep my ELSE statement in very next to IF block we are getting different error. I update my code. M not sure still what order i need to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue reolved.As i said issue with IF ELSE Condition format only.

```
    cd C:\temp\workspace\UI-Testing\UI_Automation\
IF "%Execution_File_Name%" == "Tests" (
pabot --testlevelsplit --processes 6 --ordering order_file.pabotsuitenames --variable URL:%URL% --variable project:%Project% --variable username:%UserName% --variable password:%Password% --removekeywords WUKS -d Results %Execution_File_Name%
) ELSE (
    robot --variable URL:%URL% --variable project:%Project% --variable username:%UserName% --variable password:%Password% --removekeywords WUKS -d Results Tests\%Execution_File_Name%
)

exit 0
```